# How to convert php & jqueryMobile application to apk file

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, apk, phonegap

I made an application with PHP & jQuery mobile, and now I'm looking for how to convert this application to an apk file using PhoneGap.

Is it possible to do this? And are there any tutorials to help me learn how to do it?

Comment: you can execute php files from mobile, well phonegap for example, so you have to develop a API which will get the content via ajax.. and manage the content of the application

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a fast a simple way to do it, it is better if you extended to make more real life usage:

1- download [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/)

2- Build your first app using [this tutorial](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/building-mobile-apps-with-phonegap-build/introduction-to-phonegap-build-building-your-first-app/) or using the phonegap how to get stared

3- once you have that let's go server side.. we need a API, the simplest way to do this is like this:

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
    header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
    header('Content-type: application/json'); 

    if($_GET['nameofFunction'] == 'getHomepageContent'){
        require_once('controllers/homeController.php');
        $objHome = new homeController();
        $jsonReturn = $objHome->gethome();
        echo($jsonReturn);
    }
?>
```

4- create that controller to control the request from the API, for example something like this:

```
   <?php
    class homeController {

        public function __contruct(){

        }


        public function gethome(){
            //do what ever you need here, sql query, errors handling.. and return it
                    //back to the api.
           //for example you could use something like this to return json array to the api
           // without making much effort 
         if(mysql_num_rows($yourquery) > 0){
                while($us = mysql_fetch_assoc($yourqueryResult)){
                    $output[]=$us;
                    $homeJsonResponse = json_encode($output);
                }

                return $homeJsonResponse;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

5- We are back to the phonegap application, now make sure you are including all needed files, jquery, jquerymobile, cordovajs, itouch, iscroll....

6- create the function that will execute on load and make the ajax call to the api, this will return json, [just parse with jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/), and you are good to go.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using a similler API. So I need to request my pages using Json ? this is right ?

Comment: yes, you have request your pages using json, you could use xml, but normally json files are smaller, faster and easier to parse :)

Comment: Thank you jycr753 for the help (+1)

Comment: +1 thanks, hey @jycr753 can help me to make my first own android apps through php & html5???

Comment: @RohitSutharMumbai What do you mean? the reply for the OP will definitely help you getting started, but there is some small implementations that for a non technopeasant should be easy to implement :)

Comment: @jycr753 Actually i know the php, html5, api, jquey so can i make android apps using these things with help of phonegap???

Comment: @RohitSutharMumbai yes you can, but it will be more like a webpage app, or a full ajax application, it all depends for what you will end up using the application, but for news feed, small private companies news or pages, it will do the trick :)

Comment: @RohitSutharMumbai if you have any questions you can google my username, or use that user name with plus at gmail. or here http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/49557/jycr753