# php & jqueryMobile application to apk

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, apk

I have made with the PHP & Jquery mobile for wordpress site. Now I'm looking for APK android open market. Can anyone have help me a little more details this tutorial sub: **php & jqueryMobile application to apk.**

****   Attent: jycr753****,Link: [How to convert php & jqueryMobile application to apk file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258672/how-to-convert-php-jquerymobile-application-to-apk-file) (Can you please a little details your tutorial )

I'm totally new here.

Thank you

---

"

```
    <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b" data-filter="true" data-counttheme="e">
    <?php if( have_posts() ) : while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <li>
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <h2> 
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" data-transition="slidedown"><?php the_title(); ?></a> 
        </h2>
        <article> <?php echo the_excerpt(); ?> </article>

    </li>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    </ul>       
</div>
```

"

---

Comment: take a look at phonegap

Answer (score 0):

That would be simpler , just create a sample android app with webview and load the url of your website

visit
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/

assuming that you know some basic of setting the android workspace ,

just follow the tutorial and let load your URL instead